# How do I make paging gridview that is bound to dataset on dropdwon list change event?

Tags: c#, binding, webforms, pagination, dataset

I am binding the gridview from sqlserver using dataset and datable on PageLoad.

```
public DataSet Ds
{
    get
    {
        object temp = ViewState["Ds"];
        return temp == null ? null : temp as DataSet;
    }
    set
    {
        ViewState["Ds"] = value;
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gridCustAllInfoBind();

    }
}

public void gridCustAllInfoBind()
{
    try
    {
        //open the db connection if it is closed...  
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.Open();
        command = new SqlCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Z_cust";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Connection = connection;           

        SqlDataAdapter daAcc = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

        this.Ds = new DataSet();
        daAcc.Fill(Ds);


        if (Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            Ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(Ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
            gridCustomer.DataSource = Ds;
            gridCustomer.DataBind();
            int columncount = gridCustomer.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
            gridCustomer.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
            gridCustomer.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
            gridCustomer.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
            gridCustomer.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
        }
        else
        {
            //gridCustomer.DataSource = idr;
            gridCustomer.DataSource = Ds;
            gridCustomer.DataBind();
        }           
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessagePaySerach.Text= ex.Message;
    }  
    finally //Close db Connection if it is open....  
    {
        if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            connection.Close();

    }
}
```

Here I am filtering the dataset on demand, then bind the gridview to it.

```
protected void btnSearchCust_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlStatus.SelectedIndex == 0 && ddlColumns.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        var strExpr = "Status='Active'";            

        var dv = Ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        dv.RowFilter = strExpr;
        var newDS = new DataSet();
        var newDT = dv.ToTable();
        newDS.Tables.Add(newDT);

        gridCustomer.DataSource = newDS;
        int size = int.Parse(ddlPaging.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
        gridCustomer.PageSize = size;
        gridCustomer.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Here I am selecting dropdownlist values, then I have to show gridview records on demand.

```
protected void ddlPaging_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int size = int.Parse(ddlPaging.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
    gridCustomer.PageSize = size;
    btnSearchCust_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but you probably still have to call `DataBind` and set the `PageIndex`(recalculating it from the original `PageIndex` and `PageSize`)  - http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rohatash/gridview-paging-sample-in-Asp-Net/ even with dataset preserved in the viewstate.

Comment: Also, huge DataSet can severely affect performance of the page. So you may want to consider more fine-grained pagination - http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/ASPNet-GridView-Custom-Paging-with-PageSize-Change-Dropdown.aspx. And do not forget about [ViewState security implication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff797918.aspx).

Comment: if I do like aspsnippest then i have to go sqlserver on every condition which makes heavy load on server

Comment: Serializing and desirializing huge DataSet from and to ViewState may become an even bigger bottleneck. Overall as any performance consideration it depends on your exact requirements and situation.

Comment: I alredy applied this way but i have huge conditions then have to create individual storeprocedures with different methods so on every click have to go server wich make heavy load on server, so iam looking for filter and paging on codebehind side only.so have any procedure?

Comment: That is an another question. You can search for C# SQL dynamic filtering, perhaps even try something with EF or other ORM, but, actually, there is no truly satisfying(from all points of view) solution to filtering problem as far as I know. Still, good luck.

Comment: then by which technology we can apply this concept?Jason or Jquery or any other?

Comment: Json has nothing to do with filtering - it is just a data format. jQuery can filter the items on the **client side**, but that is not a good idea other than for small sets. Basically, if you use plain ADO, you are left with two options - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482143/3745022, and of course you can filter on the server like you was doing it in the current code version depending on your requirements, but it may or may not significantly affect the performance. So if you have some specific problem or question then ask it as [a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).